# Maven 3 ejb-client dependency visible at compile time not visible at runtime for ejb 3.1 app client

Tags: maven-3, glassfish-3, ejb-3.1

I have a simple EJB 3.1 project which uses Glassfish 3.1.2 as AS and Maven 3 for dependency management. In the pom.xml of ejb project I set the generateClient option to true. I successfully deployed my ear to the server and then I tried to create a simple standalone client. Here is the pom.xml of the client:

```
<project>
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>duan</groupId>
   <artifactId>ejb31-app-client</artifactId>
   <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <name>ejb31-app-client</name>
   <description>my app client</description>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.main.appclient.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>gf-client-module</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
            <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>duan</groupId>
        <artifactId>ejb31</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>ejb-client</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

where ejb31 is my ejb project for which I client is generated.

The Java class used in my application client is:

```
public class Test {
private static HelloWorldBeanRemote helloWorldBean;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String jndiPath = "java:global/ejb31-ear-1.0/ejb31-ejb/HelloWorldBean";

    try {
        Context ctx = new InitialContext();
        System.out.println("Looking up bean at: " + jndiPath);
        helloWorldBean = (HelloWorldBeanRemote) ctx.lookup(jndiPath);
        System.out.println("Found helloWorldBean:" + helloWorldBean);
        System.out.println("Calling sayHello():");
        String greeting = helloWorldBean.sayHello();
        System.out.println("HelloWorldBean said:" + greeting);
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        System.err.println("Could not find HelloWorldBeanRemote!");
        System.err.println("JNDI path used for lookup:" + jndiPath);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

The application client is compiled without problem by Maven. If I run this from Eclipse I get this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ro.duan.ejb.HelloWorldBeanRemote
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.ejb.EJBUtils.getBusinessIntfClassLoader(EJBUtils.java:688)
    at com.sun.ejb.EJBUtils.loadGeneratedRemoteBusinessClasses(EJBUtils.java:463)
    at com.sun.ejb.EJBUtils.lookupRemote30BusinessObject(EJBUtils.java:414)
    ... 7 more
```

But then if I manually add ejb-client.jar to the build path it works like a charm. So my conclusion is that somehow ejb-client.jar is available at compile time, but not at runtime. Any thoughts on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following line:

```
<scope>compile</scope>
```

Read more about dependency scope at:

http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope